# First call .net webservice slow. Already tried web config proxy = false

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made an application with Xamarin Forms and everything is working fine except that the first call to my .net webservice is very slow (8s-15s) and then all calls are from 1s - 4s.

My Web.config:

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="False" />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My webservice:

```
SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***.***.***.****;persist security info=False;initial catalog=####; User ID=####;pwd=####;Packet Size=4096;Connection Timeout=3");
Con.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(string.Format(message), Con);
return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any ideas to make the first call faster?

Comment: Is the first query different form the rest? How long does the SQL execution of the first query takes compare to the rest?

Comment: @EvZ thank you for your reply. No, the first query is only a "select *" with 5 rows and 5 columns, the others are also a "select *" but they have more data. When I make the request again (without closong the app) it takes less time to execute the query. The first takes around 10 seconds and the rest take 2 seconds.